# Category name from path using CanActivate. Missing categories from observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, routes, frontend

I'm trying check category exists in my database before CanActive route to module.

My app-routing.module.ts:

```
....
      }, {
        path: ':mainCategory',
        canActivate: [CategoriesGuard],
        loadChildren: '../app/modules/categories/categories.module#CategoriesModule'
      }
....
```

CategoriesGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { CategoriesService } from "@app/shared/services/categories.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, public categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }

    private categoryExists: boolean;

    private categories$: Observable<any>;

    public categories: any;


    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        const categoryFromParam = route.paramMap.get('mainCategory');
        this.getCategories();

        // Here should check categories exists in database
        const category = this.categories.filter(x => x.categoryName = categoryFromParam);
        if (category.lenght) {
            return true
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['404']);
            return false
        }
    }

    private getCategories(): void {
        this.categories$ = this.categoriesService.getCategories();
        this.categories$.subscribe(categories => {
            this.categories = categories;
        })
    };}
```

method categoriesService.getCategories()

```
      public getCategories() {
           return this.http.get<any>(this.categoriesEndpoint).pipe(
               map(response => { return response })
            );
    }
```

My categories are undefied because method canActivate not waiting to get categories from backend. How it should looks in proper way?
Is it a good idea to do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

`canActivate` can also return an observable of boolean, so instead of subscribing, do just that:

```ts
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const categoryFromParam = route.paramMap.get('mainCategory');
    return this.categoriesService.getCategories().pipe(
      map((categories: any) => {
         const category = this.categories.filter(x => x.categoryName = categoryFromParam);
         if (category.length) {
           return true
         }
         this.router.navigate(['404']);
         return false
      })
   );
}
```